Running AWS EMR via Step Functions - How to have have "Terminated with errors" when a Step Fails
I'm in the process of migrating ETL jobs from Talend to AWS. The ETL Jobs are pyspark scripts that run on AWS EMR. A typical job on Talend will run multiple pyspark scripts in sequence. My understanding of how this works in Talend is that Talend creates an AWS CLI command (via aws emr create-cluster) that starts the cluster, runs the scripts in sequence, and terminates upon completion. This works fine. If a particular script fails, any subsequent scripts will still run because "ActionOnFailure":"CONTINUE" is set in the --steps flag. The result is that if all steps run fine, the high-level message I'll see in EMR is Terminated - All steps completed. If one or multiple steps fail, I'll instead see Terminated with errors - Step failure. Because these labels are visible from the EMR Clusters page, it's fairly easy to see which clusters failed and which passed in the last day.
Now that I'm migrating to AWS Step Functions though, the behavior is different. Step Functions is forcing me to use one step to create the cluster (arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:createCluster), one step per script I want to run (arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep), and one step to terminate the cluster (arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:terminateCluster). Because there is a specific step to terminate the cluster, all clusters report Terminated - User Request whether or not they have any steps that failed. This means I can no longer visually see at a glance which clusters failed and which succeeded, without clicking into the clusters themselves to see what happened.
I tried replicating the CLI functionality in Step Functions, but the documentation specifically says here that "The field Steps is not allowed." for createCluster
I'm guessing that what I'm trying to do isn't possible with Step Functions and I have to accept that from the EMR Cluster page, there won't be a visual distinction between clusters with errors and those without anymore. I understand that Step Functions has error handling via Catch blocks and that I'm able to take actions (e.g. send an email) based on a Step failure.
I also think an option is to use Lambda instead of EMR to replicate the CLI functionality.
I think another thing that's relevant is right now my CLI command runs all scripts it's given in order regardless of if any of them fail. My Step Functions Workflow is set up to emulate that behavior. If I change the behavior to terminate the cluster after a failed step (i.e. set "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER" for a Step), then the cluster indeed reports Terminated with errors). So I think this is one of two options I have. The other is to make use of Step Functions' ability to detect failure (i.e. the Catch block) to send an error email or otherwise log an error. Maybe I can create a dashboard with all my clusters that fail?
If anyone has any suggestions for me, they are much appreciated!
